# How can I show that $E[(\hat\theta -\theta)^2]<Var(\bar X)=\dfrac{1}{n}$?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\theta, 1),\theta_0 \lt\theta$ ,  Find the MLE of $\theta$ and show that it is better than the sample mean $\bar X$ in the sense of having smaller mean squared error.

Trial: Here MLE of $\theta$ is $$\hat\theta =
\begin{cases}
\theta_0, &\bar X \lt \theta_0\\
\bar X, &\theta_0 \le \bar X  \\
\end{cases}$$

I can't show that $E[(\hat\theta -\theta)^2] \lt Var(\bar X)=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat I think that the other question really is a duplicate of this one if we allow $\theta_1$ in the other question to increase without bound. I am voting to close this one.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I agree